# How to mock a property inside a class in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

This is my first file called user.py

```
from account import Account    
class User:
   def __init__(self, id):
       self.id = id
       self._account = None

   @property
   def account(self):
       if not self._account:
          self._account = Account(self.id)

       return self._account

   @property
   def has_discount(self)
       return self.account.discount_id > 0
```

I have a second file called account.py

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        # some process to load DB data
        self.account = load_account(user_id)
        # do something after this to initialize account properties like discount, etc

    @property
    def discount_id(self):
       return self.discount_id
```

My goal is to test user.py.  One of the things I want to do is to mock the Account object in user.py for the 'has_discount' property decorator.  I want to test different scenarios where has_discount will return either 0 or any other number.

How do I do this using patch where I can mock the Account object in the User class to return custom values so I can try different tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `user` module imports `Account` in to its own namespace [patching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) has to be done there instead of the `account` module. In other words you have to temporarily change what the name `Account` in the `user` module refers to:

```
from user import User
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch('user.Account') as MockAccount:
    MockAccount.return_value.discount_id = 1
    u = User(1)                             
    print(u.has_discount)
    # True

with patch('user.Account') as MockAccount:
    MockAccount.return_value.discount_id = 0
    u = User(1)
    print(u.has_discount)
    # False
```

> I want to test different scenarios where has_discount will return either 0 or any other number.

In its current implementation `User.has_discount` will always return either `True` or `False`. Did you mean `Account.discount_id`?