# How to mock the default value of a property method in Django model during unit testing?

Tags: django

I have below model in Django and it has a property method.

```
class Company(ExtendedModel):
    name = TruncatingCharField(verbose_name='Company Name', max_length=100, default="NewCo", blank=True)
    groupId = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    partner = models.ForeignKey('Partner', related_name='companies', null=True)
    parentCompany = models.ForeignKey(
        'register_company.Company', related_name='linkedCompanies', null=True, blank=True
    )
    
@property
def isLiveOnPayroll(self):
    from payroll.models import APCompany

    apCompany = APCompany.objects.filter(company_id=self.id).last()

    return bool(
            apCompany
            and all(
                [
                    self.isReal,
                    self.isActive,
                    self.isPayroll,
                    apCompany.isOnboardedAndActive,
                ]
            )
        )
```

In unittest when I read values from this model, I need to set the default value of property method isLiveOnPayroll default to True. In other words I need to mock the value of this method.

Please assist how to set it.

I tried to mock it using mocker, however could not find the any solution so far.

Comment: Below link has most relevant answer to my question,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019244/how-to-mock-a-property-inside-a-class-in-python